# Появление графических артефактов при рисовании с помощью canvas на прозрачном фоне

Tags: android, canvas, opacity

В приложении - рисовалке есть такой код:

```
case "LINE":
                {
                    switch (eve.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                       
                            {
                                if(eve.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                                {
                                x1 = x2 = X;
                                y1 = y2 = Y;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                x2 = X;
                                y2 = Y;
                                }

                                pth.reset();
                                pth.moveTo(x1, y1);
                                pth.lineTo(x2, y2);

                                c_tmp = SH.lockCanvas();
                                c_tmp.drawARGB(a,r,g,b);
                                c_tmp.drawBitmap(b_main, 0,0, null);
                                c_tmp.drawPath(pth, p_sten);
                                SH.unlockCanvasAndPost(c_tmp);
                            }
                            break;


                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            {

                                c_main.drawPath(pth_tmp, p_main);
                                nextBit();

                                c_tmp = SH.lockCanvas();
                                c_tmp.drawARGB(a,r,g,b);
                                c_tmp.drawBitmap(b_main, 0,0, null);
                                SH.unlockCanvasAndPost(c_tmp);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
```

При повторяющейся перерисовке на полностью непрозрачном фоне всё рисуется как надо , но если фон хотя бы частично прозрачен - то ранее отрисованные линии остаются , хотя системный canvas 
(и связанный с ним системный bitmap) уже другой:

[image: графические артифакты]

Пробовал вызывать destroyDrawingCache для surfaceview и менять его layerType - не помогло , что это и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется разобрался : похоже что системный canvas использует набор из нескольких (кажется четырёх) bitmap , которые поочерёдно - циклически вставляются в него перед его возвращением , при этом ранее использованные bitmap не очищаются и через несколько вызовов lockCanvas они снова используются , сохраняя на себе следы прежних отрисовок - отсюда и "артифакты" ; 
Исправляется это вызовом `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT , PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);` для canvas при каждом его получении